# Concat tensors in tensorflow TF 2.0

Tags: stack, append, concatenation, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I have two tensors os shapes [2,1,30] and [2,181,30]. I would like to append them to be of shape [2,182,30]. Any ideas how to achieve that?

I couldn't use either `tf.concat` or `tf.stack` as they both result in error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [2,1,30] vs. shape[1] = [2,181,30]
         [[{{node concat}}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably didn't specify the axis for `tf.concat`

```
a = tf.random.normal(shape=[2,1,30])
b = tf.random.normal(shape=[2, 181, 30])

c = tf.concat([a,b], axis=1)
```